# bootstrap nav click dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap  menu dropdown not working
it works fine when i did in codepen but when i put the code in my site. it doesnot work.
help
i have included all css and js i.e.bootstrap.css,bootstrap.min.css,bootstrap-theme.css,bootstrap-theme.min.css,font-awesome.min.css,font-awesome.css as well as reset.css and my own custom.css

my code for navbar is as follows

```
<div class"nav-outer-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <li class="active dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

use this add `<li>` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I ones had that challenge, you also need to add pooper.min.js (here is the cdn link for popper https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js) and bootstrap.bundle.min.js scripts in that order in the head section of your project. make sure you have both files if you are not using the CDN link.in your project. this should resolve your error.